# Why is my Eevee viewport render different from my full render?

Tags: rendering, particles, eevee-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I'm a little confused why my Eevee render looks different from the viewport preview.
[image]
Above - Preview
[image]
Above - Render

Just a bit confused here. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote an answer I got elsewhere,

> What makes the rendered image look dark is the volume material of the
>   particle emitter. However, the emitter is not shown because you have
>   to enable “show emitter” in the particle options :slight_smile:
>   Unfortunately, the “show emitter” checkbox doesnt have influece on the
>   viewport so you always need to double check if it’s turned on or off.
>    --eaNiiX